# Как просмотреть работу индексаторов в пошаговой отладке в VS 2010?

Tags: c#

Как с помощью пошаговой отладки в VS 2010 посмотреть в каком порядке вызываются и работают аксесоры get и set? С помощью использования клавиши F11(Step Into) мне не удается это просмотреть.

```
class FailSoftArray
{
    private int[] a;

    public int Length;
    public bool ErrFlag;

    public FailSoftArray(int size)
    {
        a = new int[size];
        Length = size;
    }

    public int this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            if (ok(index))
            {
                ErrFlag = false;
                return a[index];
            }
            else
            {
                ErrFlag = true;
                return 0;
            }
        }

        set
        {
            if (ok(index))
            {
                a[index] = value;
                ErrFlag = false;
            }

            else
            {
                ErrFlag = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private bool ok(int index)
    {
        if (index >= 0 & index < Length) return true;
        return false;
    }
}

class FsDemo
{
    static void Main()
    {
        FailSoftArray fs = new FailSoftArray(5);
        int x;

        Console.WriteLine("Скрытый сбой.");
        for (int i = 0; i < (fs.Length * 2); i++)
            fs[i] = i * 10;

        for (int i = 0; i < (fs.Length * 2); i++)
        {
            x = fs[i];
            if (x != -1) Console.Write(x + " ");
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("\nСбой с уведомлением об ошибках.");
        for (int i = 0; i < (fs.Length * 2); i++)
        {
            fs[i] = i * 10;
            if (fs.ErrFlag)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("fs[" + i + "] вне границ");
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < (fs.Length * 2); i++)
        {
            x = fs[i];
            if (!fs.ErrFlag)
            {
                Console.Write(x + " ");
            }

            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("fs[" + i + "] вне границ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: метод:

    private bool ok(int index)
    {
        if (index >= 0 && index < Length) return true;
        return false;
    }

эквивалентен:

    private bool ok(int index)
    {
        return index >= 0 && index < Length;
    }

Comment: @ArniLand, я рекомендую Вам получше усвоить правила форума. У нас не приветствуются вопросы, большую часть которых занимает листинг в несколько экранов. Кроме того, в данном вопросе он вообще не нужен.

Answer (score 1):

Я знаю только один способ: поставить точку останова непосредственно в индексатор.

Ещё можно попытаться порыться в Tools / Options / Debugging